# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php

Ошибка в 5 строке, что я не так делаю?

```
class Main_PopupTemplate 
    {
        public $arg = null;

        public function setMark($k) {
            $this->arg = func_get_arg(0);
        }

        public function getMark() {
            $discTexts = $this->getArg();
            $result = isset($discTexts[$this->arg]) ? $discTexts[$this->arg] : null;

            return $result;
        }

        public static function getArg()
        {
            return array(
                'disclaimer-01' => 'Text-1',
                'disclaimer-02' => 'Text-2',
                'disclaimer-03' => 'Text-3',
                'disclaimer-04' => 'Text-4'
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Со статическими свойствами и методами все ок работало, но от статических надо избавиться было.

Comment: А вы обращаетесь к нему как к статическому методу `$a = Main_PopupTemplate::setMark(...);` посмотрите по стеку

Comment: А это `public static function` что?

Comment: 5 строка - это какая? Сейчас у вас 5 строка - это `public function setMark($k) {` И ваш код на [работает без сообщений](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/67fa648f86f6224939a5067ec4e2390ae5f6aa3c)

Comment: Вызываю как статический да... из хтмл шаблона вызываю. Как вызвать правильно?

Comment: `$a = new Main_PopupTemplate; $a->setMark(1);`

Comment: @BOPOH  я думаю. там вызовы остались. когда статические методы были

Comment: @user3510544 ну и что нового вам сказали на английском стеке? :)))